# IAM credentials error 404

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

Running on an ec2 instance in us-east-1, I'm having trouble getting boto to use IAM for authentication. The AMI is a recent Amazon linux.

```
$ python
Python 2.6.8 (unknown, Mar 14 2013, 09:31:22) 
[GCC 4.6.2 20111027 (Red Hat 4.6.2-2)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import boto
>>> boto.__version__
'2.13.3'
>>> c = boto.connect_s3()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto/__init__.py", line 135, in connect_s3
    return S3Connection(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 174, in __init__
    validate_certs=validate_certs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 557, in __init__
    host, config, self.provider, self._required_auth_capability())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto/auth.py", line 728, in get_auth_handler
    'Check your credentials' % (len(names), str(names)))
boto.exception.NoAuthHandlerFound: No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handlers were checked. ['HmacAuthV1Handler'] Check your credentials
```

Thanks to https://github.com/boto/boto/pull/1175 I was able to get a little more information. Apparently it's trying to use IAM, but failing.

```
>>> import os
>>> boto.set_stream_logger('boto')
>>> c = boto.connect_s3()
2013-09-26 21:52:11,685 boto [DEBUG]:Retrieving credentials from metadata server.
2013-09-26 21:52:11,688 boto [ERROR]:Caught exception reading instance data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto/utils.py", line 211, in retry_url
    r = opener.open(req)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 397, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 510, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 435, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 518, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
2013-09-26 21:52:11,725 boto [ERROR]:Unable to read instance data, giving up
```

A quick tcpdump agrees: boto connects to `instance-data.ec2.internal` with `GET /latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/` and then receives `404 Not Found`. That seems to be the first and only HTTP request. So far I haven't been able to find any reports of a similar issue, but maybe boto should supply a role name at the end of that `GET` request path?

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong? How might I debug this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
boto.exception.NoAuthHandlerFound: [...] Check your credentials
```

As you are using IAM, you have to ensure that you have sufficient permission for S3, i.e. by attaching the policy `Amazon S3 Full Access` at your user.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I no longer have access to the IAM account in question, but that sounds plausible. The IAM account was able to do everything I needed to in the AWS console, but it makes sense that boto might need additional privileges.